# .animate() query not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I wanted to implement a "Scroll back to top" button in my static HTML site, like I've done it a million times before. So I added this code:
(first part is about making the button appear after a certain time, don't worry about that)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        var wheight = $(window).height();
        var hheight = wheight / 2;
        if(scroll >= hheight) {
            $('#scroller').css({'opacity': '1'});
        } else if (scroll <= hheight) {
            $('#scroller').css({'opacity': '0'});
        }
    });

    $('#scroller').click(function() {
        alert("click works!");
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
    });
});
```

The appearing and disappearing of the button works and it also alerts "click works" if I click the button. But the scrolling won't work. I am lost. I read somewhere that you shouldn't use `height: 100%` in your CSS and use

```
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
```

instead. That won't change a thing. I've also tried to use `document` as the element to scroll.

I am glad if someone can help me!

Comment: Could you provide the html ? If you have `html, body, #wrapper { height: 100%; }`, you might have to change your code by `$('html, body, #wrapper').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);`

Comment: unfortunately that won't work either :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code works:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        var wheight = $(window).height();
        var hheight = wheight / 2;
        if(scroll >= hheight) {
            $('#scroller').css({'opacity': '1'});
        } else if (scroll <= hheight) {
            $('#scroller').css({'opacity': '0'});
        }
    });

    $('.scroll').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red, blue);
  height: 2000px;
  border: 10px solid goldenrod;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="scroll">scroll</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!
I used the slim version of jQuery.
As soon as I switched to the normal production version everything worked.